# Strange behavior with boost::any / any_ostreamable

Tags: c++

The following code prints 666666, though I wanted 12345.

What's wrong ? How to fix it ?

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/operators.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::type_erasure;
using namespace std;

typedef any<boost::mpl::vector<boost::type_erasure::typeid_<>, ostreamable<>>, const _self&> any_ostreamable;
typedef std::vector<any_ostreamable> any_ostreamable_vector;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  any_ostreamable_vector args;
  for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    args.emplace_back(i);
  for (auto& arg: args)
    cout << arg;
}
```

At first, I thought that it was because *i* was captured by reference in the any_ostreamable, hance 5 times the same reference, and the value 6, the value that *i* has when going out of the loop.

So I tried to replace `args.emplace_back(i);` by args.emplace_back(i`+0);`, passing a rvalue, forcing to construct a new int.
Lost! In that case I obtain 55555. By using i+1 I get 66666, i+2 77777, etc.

By saying `args.emplace_back(int(i));`, I also get 66666.

I have even tried `args.emplace_back(i*i);`, but again I obtain 2525252525 instead of 1491625.

If I observe iteration after iteration what the vector contains, I get something like 1, 22, 333, 4444, 55555. So even if I write `i+0`, `int(i)` or `i*i`, any_ostreamable seem to capture 5 times the same reference.

All the above gave the same results if I use push_back instead of emplace_back.
That's also the same if I write `i+n` with any n!=0.

The same thing also happens if I use doubles instead of ints, and even with elaborately constructed str::string.

Can someone explain what's going on ?

How can I obtain the desired output ? If possible without changing the any_ostreamable typedef. That's the only thing I hadn't tried, because I'm not sure to understand how/what I can change without creating unexpected side effects elsewhere in the real program.

Compiler: MinGW32 with G++ 5.3.0, compiling in C++14.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have dangling references to objects that no longer exist.  The result is undefined behaviour when you follow the dangling references.

Reference based type erasure is reasonable as function APIs; otherwise it is a bad plan.

Comment: Thank you. So what can I do to tell it to capture by values instead of references ? Do I have to decide once for everywhere or can I decide at any_ostreamable construction to capture by value or by reference ?
Is there a way to fix this code while keeping capture by reference ?

Comment: @quent I believe this part `const _self&>`  is where you tell it to capture by reference.

Comment: @quen try `copy_constructible<>` instead of `_self const&`.

Comment: Yes, it works with copy_constructible<> ! Thank you. Sadly it means that a copy is made everywhere. Answer accepted.

Comment: @QuentinC a value type and a ref type is a different thing, and you should have both types; `view_ostreamable` and `value_ostreamable` or somesuch.

Comment: It's not so simple: in the real project, it would require duplicating hundreds of lines of code. I don't see how I could do without duplication, and I don't have the impression that it is really worth it in my case. The most complicated object that will have to be uselessly copied sometimes is std::string. That's sad but probably not so critical either.

Comment: @QuentinC Code should either (A) want to own something, or (B) not want to own something.  Code that is ambiguous about if it owns something is a serious problem.  (Note that you can pass an `value_ostreamable` to a `view_ostreamable` interface.)  So you should have very little code where a variable could be both a view and a value and the code still makes sense.  Now, sometimes you want a view from which you can spawn a value, but that is a different thing entirely.